# how to compile gcc 3.4 on archlinux?

Tags: gcc, archlinux

I solve it by modify other version's gcc aur file. It is amazing that i got success. I edit form gcc43 in aur.
But i don't know why...

I have try to use

```
yaourt -S gcc34
```

but i get wrong. It notice me that:

```
   ^
../../gcc-3.4.6/libiberty/cplus-dem.c: ‘demangle_nested_args’中:
../../gcc-3.4.6/libiberty/cplus-dem.c:4585:7: 警告：隐式声明与内建函数‘free’不兼容 [默认启用]
       free ((char *) work->previous_argument);
       ^
../../gcc-3.4.6/libiberty/cplus-dem.c: 在函数‘string_delete’中:
../../gcc-3.4.6/libiberty/cplus-dem.c:4788:7: 警告：隐式声明与内建函数‘free’不兼容 [默认启用]
       free (s->b);
       ^
make[1]: *** [cplus-dem.o] 错误 1
make[1]: 离开目录“/tmp/yaourt-tmp-cnmpp902/aur-gcc34/src/gcc-build/libiberty”
make: *** [all-libiberty] 错误 2
```

How can i deal with it ?
And what about other methods?

Thank you!

Comment: GCC 3.4 is getting quite old, why do you need that version specifically? (Also you'll get better chances at finding your problem using search engines of you get the error messages in English. Try something like `LANG=C yaourt ...`.)

Answer (score 0):

GCC 3.4 is too old. It's usually difficult to build a large application written many years ago with a current compiler. It is very common that one or two developers were unaware that their code was dependent on some features or even bugs of toolchains then available. This is true in GCC, in the Linux kernel, and in many large applications.

If you really want GCC 3.4, I suggest you install GCC 4.1 first and then build GCC 3.4 with GCC 4.1.

Comment: Thank you to answer my question,I will test it.

Comment: I solve it by modify other version's gcc aur file. It is amazing that i got success. I edit form gcc43 in aur.

Comment: Could you please put your GCC 3.4 PKGBUILD to AUR?